# Is there a way to set global preferences in altair?

Tags: python, altair

Is there a way to do something like a rc file with Altair?

I currently create an Altair theme at the beginning of my notebooks (to set up plot size and font size, etc.) and then register and enable it.

```
alt.themes.register('my-chart', my_theme)
alt.themes.enable('my-chart')
```

What is the best way to refactor this away to a global config file of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't  think there is a file that Altair reads at startup. If  you want to avoid copy pasting the same theme code into each notebook, you can create a Python package with your theme. There are [several examples of how to set this up on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=altair%20theme) e.g. [this la times theme](https://github.com/datadesk/altair-latimes).

Comment: Thanks! This is basically what I need.